# In ansible, what's the best way to gather and merge vars from different roles and use in a dependent role?

Tags: ansible

If I have a common baseline Ansible role but want to contribute data to that role from other different modules, what's the best way to achieve this?

For example: I have a role called `firewall` that manages a system's firewall, and two other roles `webserver` and `mailserver`. The `webserver` role knows it needs to configure a firewall rule allowing traffic on ports tcp80/443, and `mailserver` knows it needs to contribute a firewall rule allowing traffic on tcp25.

I only want to execute the `firewall` role once.

If I add `firewall` as dependencies of `mailserver` and `webserver` and called with different vars, the firewall rule runs multiple times.

One option might be to have `firewall` run last of all, and have the other roles run `set_fact`, appending their own list of rules to an existing variable that `firewall` can then apply.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

The tasks of a dependant role are running **before** the role in which it is listed as a dependency, so, this does not really seems like it fits your use case.

This said, your use case looks like the perfect fit for a *handler*. The said handler can be [made available as part of a role](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_handlers.html#handlers-in-roles).

Given:

*roles/firewall/handlers/main.yml*:

```yaml
- name: List ports
  debug:
    msg: "Configure firewall here with {{ item }}"
  loop: "{{ firewall_ports | default([]) }}"
  listen: "firewall : Configure firewall"

- name: Second task
  debug:
    msg: This is a example of a second task needed to configure a firewall
  listen: "firewall : Configure firewall"
```

*roles/mailserver/meta/main.yml*:

```yaml
dependencies:
  - role: firewall
```

*roles/mailserver/tasks/main.yml*:

```yaml
- set_fact:
    firewall_ports: "{{ firewall_ports | default([]) + [25] }}"
  # Note that we do need a changed state to notify a handler
  # hence we need a `changed_when: true` 
  # since this is the only task of the role
  # Since you will have other tasks, make sure to place the `notify`
  # on a task causing a changed state
  changed_when: true
  notify: "firewall : Configure firewall"
```

*roles/webserver/meta/main.yml*:

```yaml
dependencies:
  - role: firewall
```

*roles/webserver/tasks/main.yml*:

```yaml
- set_fact:
    firewall_ports: "{{ firewall_ports | default([]) + [80, 443] }}"
  # Note that we do need a changed state to notify a handler
  # hence we need a `changed_when: true` 
  # since this is the only task of the role
  # Since you will have other tasks, make sure to place the `notify`
  # on a task causing a changed state
  changed_when: true
  notify: "firewall : Configure firewall"
```

Playbook:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  roles:
    - webserver
    - mailserver
```

Would yield:

```
PLAY [localhost] *********************************************************

TASK [webserver : set_fact] **********************************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [mailserver : set_fact] *********************************************
changed: [localhost]

RUNNING HANDLER [firewall : List ports] **********************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=80) => 
  msg: configure firewall here with 80
ok: [localhost] => (item=443) => 
  msg: configure firewall here with 443
ok: [localhost] => (item=25) => 
  msg: configure firewall here with 25

RUNNING HANDLER [firewall : Second task] *********************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: This is a second task needed to configure a firewall
```

Comment: It's an interesting approach, firing handlers across roles. Negates the need to include the firewall role specifically. I think some cleverness would be needed in the firewall role handler to do the one-time-only tasks (like, install the fw package), just once, and not every time.

Comment: The installation of the fw package can be done as a task of that role. Either way, installing a package is an idempotent task, so it will show for each run of the playbook but won't reinstall it regardless.

Answer (score 1):

You can merge such lists on your own if you control the roles and the namespace. For example, create *defaults*

```yaml
shell> cat roles/mailserver/defaults/main/fw.yml 
ms_fw_allow: [25]
```

```yaml
shell> cat roles/webserver/defaults/main/fw.yml 
ws_fw_allow: [80, 443]
```

```yaml
shell> cat roles/firewall/defaults/main/fw.yml 
fw_fw_allow: []
```

In a play, [*include*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/include_role_module.html#ansible-builtin-include-role-module-load-and-execute-a-role) the roles and set [*public*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/include_role_module.html#parameter-public)*: true*

> *"This option dictates whether the role’s vars and defaults are exposed to the play. If set to true the variables will be available to tasks following the include_role task."*

```yaml
    - include_role:
        name: "{{ item_role }}"
        public: true
      loop:
        - webserver
        - mailserver
        - firewall
      loop_control:
        loop_var: item_role
```

In the role *firewall* find all variables that match the pattern *'.*_fw_allow'*

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: "{{ lookup('varnames', '.*_fw_allow') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  msg: ws_fw_allow,ms_fw_allow,fw_fw_allow
```

and merge(flatten) the lists

```yaml
- set_fact:
    fw_allow: "{{ lookup('vars', *q('varnames', '.*_fw_allow'))|
                  flatten|unique }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  fw_allow: [80, 443, 25]
```

Depending on your use case you can put the declaration of *fw_allow* [elsewhere](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable). For example, into the role's defaults

```yaml
shell> cat roles/firewall/defaults/main/fw.yml
fw_fw_allow: []
fw_allow: "{{ lookup('vars', *q('varnames', '.*_fw_allow'))|
              flatten|unique }}"
```

Make sure the name of the variable *fw_allow* doesn't conflict with the pattern *'.*_fw_allow'*. Use this list to configure the firewall.

---

Example of a complete project for testing

```bash
shell> tree .
.
├── ansible.cfg
├── hosts
├── pb.yml
└── roles
    ├── firewall
    │   ├── defaults
    │   │   └── main
    │   │       └── fw.yml
    │   └── tasks
    │       └── main.yml
    ├── mailserver
    │   ├── defaults
    │   │   └── main
    │   │       └── fw.yml
    │   └── tasks
    │       └── main.yml
    └── webserver
        ├── defaults
        │   └── main
        │       └── fw.yml
        └── tasks
            └── main.yml
```

```ini
shell> cat ansible.cfg
[defaults]
gathering = explicit
collections_path = $HOME/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/
inventory = $PWD/hosts
roles_path = $PWD/roles
retry_files_enabled = false
stdout_callback = yaml
```

```ini
shell> cat hosts
localhost
```

```yaml
shell> cat roles/webserver/defaults/main/fw.yml 
ws_fw_allow: [80, 443]

shell> cat roles/mailserver/defaults/main/fw.yml 
ms_fw_allow: [25]

shell> cat roles/firewall/defaults/main/fw.yml 
fw_fw_allow: []
fw_allow: "{{ lookup('vars', *q('varnames', '.*_fw_allow'))|
              flatten|unique }}"
```

```yaml
shell> cat roles/webserver/tasks/main.yml 
- debug:
    msg: Install webserver.

shell> cat roles/mailserver/tasks/main.yml 
- debug:
    msg: Install mailserver.

shell> cat roles/firewall/tasks/main.yml 
- debug:
    msg: "{{ lookup('varnames', '.*_fw_allow') }}"
  when: debug|d(false)|bool

- debug:
    var: fw_allow|to_yaml
  when: debug|d(false)|bool
```

Add other lists if you want to. For example, *local_fw_allow*

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml 
- hosts: all

  vars:

    local_fw_allow: [22]

  tasks:

    - include_role:
        name: "{{ item_role }}"
        public: true
      loop:
        - webserver
        - mailserver
        - firewall
      loop_control:
        loop_var: item_role
```

gives

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook -e debug=true pb.yml 

PLAY [all] ************************************************************************************

TASK [include_role : {{ item_role }}] **************************************************************

TASK [webserver : debug] **********************************************************************
ok: [localhosts] => 
  msg: Install webserver.

TASK [mailserver : debug] *********************************************************************
ok: [localhosts] => 
  msg: Install mailserver.

TASK [firewall : debug] ***********************************************************************
ok: [localhosts] => 
  msg: ws_fw_allow,ms_fw_allow,fw_fw_allow,local_fw_allow

TASK [firewall : debug] ***********************************************************************
ok: [localhosts] => 
  fw_allow|to_yaml: |-
    [80, 443, 25, 22]

PLAY RECAP ************************************************************************************
localhosts: ok=4    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: Nice. i like the idea of not needing to call `set_fact` in the service playbook, but rather just have the firewall role gather up all the vars that match the pattern. As you say, I control the whole namespace, so that feels reasonable. `lookup('vars')` was the bit of knowledge I was missing.

Comment: The best place for the declaration of the merged list is the role defaults directory, I think. I updated the answer with this option.